# How do I prevent duplicate entries from getting saved in Sqlalchemy postgresql table?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am working on a project using SQLAlchemy and PostgresQl database. I am trying to save the entries in two tables. Structure and Bandit_Page. My issue is that,I am trying to save the entries into the Bandit_Pages table in which the last two numbers are being added by me when I add it from my flask page whereas the entries above it are being saved automatically. To give you an insight,here is my code in which I have defined the Classes:

```
class Structure(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'structure'

    arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    page_url = db.Column(db.String())

class Bandit_pages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bandit_pages'
    campaign_id = db.Column(db.String())
    arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('campaign_id', 'arm_id'),
        {},)
```

here is the code in which the data is being added automatically.:

```
def init(self):
    ###code
    self.structure = {0: "xyz.php"}
    try:
        for arm_id in self.structure:
             new_bandit_page = Bandit_pages(campaign_id=arm_id, arm_id=arm_id, status=True)
             new_bandit_page_1 = Bandit_pages(campaign_id=arm_id, arm_id=arm_id+1, status=False)
             db.session.add_all([new_bandit_page, new_bandit_page_1])
             db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
           print("exception in BANDPAGEINIT insert", e)
           db.session.rollback()
```

And this is how the data is being added in the Bandit_pages table:

```
myproj=# select * from bandit_pages ;
 campaign_id | arm_id | status 
-------------+--------+--------
           0 |      0 | t
           0 |      1 | f
           0 |      0 | t
           0 |      1 | f
    43137797 |      1 | f
    43137797 |      0 | t
(6 rows)
```

The last two values(4313779) is being added my myself when I want a new page and the campaign_id 0 is being replicated twice.
So what I want was this table:

```
myproj=# select * from bandit_pages ;

 campaign_id | arm_id | status 
-------------+--------+--------
           0 |      0 | t
           0 |      1 | f
    43137797 |      1 | f
    43137797 |      0 | t
(4 rows)
```

But I got the the entries replicated. So I've tried things like using distinct(),scalar(),first(),limit() in my code but doing so simply removed all the entries with campaign_id=0 leaving the table with the values for campaign_id=43137797. I Have even tried setting up the campaign_id with a primary key but that didn't save any value into the table.
How do I prevent getting the entries from getting replicated into the table? Please help me out.

Comment: Please show the schema of the actual table in the DB.

Comment: @IljaEverilä please check my edited question

Comment: It looks like the actual table does not have a primary key constraint in place, so the DB allows duplicates.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I had earlier used a unique key constraint I solved my solution however if I've to add new entries to the table with some other campaign_id and the same arm_id then it doesn't save into the tables.

Comment: You set campaign_id based on arm_id, so having another campaign_id will not matter. Not being able to insert duplicates when a primary key or unique constraint is in place is the correct and expected behaviour. You will have to then decide what to do in that case.

Comment: could you please give me an example of how to set campaign_id based on arm_id ? @IljaEverilä