# How do I make a foreign key to an already created PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables table 1:

```
cs111=# \d structure;
              Table "public.structure"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 page_url | text    |           |          | 
 arm_id   | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "structure_arm_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (arm_id)
```

and table 2:

```
cs111=# \d bandit_pages;
              Table "public.bandit_pages"
   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 campaign_id | text    |           |          | 
 arm_id      | integer |           |          | 
 status      | boolean |           |          |
```

I want to make `arm_id` from `structure` table to be a foreign key for `bandit_pages` table but on the column of `campaign_id`. These tables are already made so I am unsure how to alter these tables. Please help.

Comment: Do you have data under `campaign_id` column?

Comment: That's impossible. `arm_id` is an integer, `campaign_id` is a text (string) value. How could a value like `42` reference a value like `'summer_69'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well I am using sqlalchemy with flask to create the tables and insert the data..so technically where Im adding them Im looping it by making the variable as 'str',so the data is getting into campaign id as '0' or '1' or '333'

Comment: ***NEVER***, ever store numbers in `text` (or `varchar`) columns. Just don't.

Comment: But why doesn't `structure.arm_id` reference `bandit_pages.arm_id`? I would assume that columns with the same name would contain the same "thing". If `bandit_pages.arm_id` is something different, then why give it the same name? And if they do contain the same thing, then why doesn't `bandit_pages.arm_id` not reference `structure.arm_id`?

Comment: From your other questions you seem to be using flask-sqlalchemy, so you might find [flask-migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

The whole questions seems to be going in the wrong direction, but anyway.

Under the following assumptions:

1. `campaign_id` is actually a number incorrectly stored as a string
2. `campaign_id` does indeed store the value of `structure.arm_id`

then, you can create the foreign key using the following steps:

```sql
-- convert campaign_id to a proper integer
alter table bandit_pages
  alter campaign_id type integer using campaign_id::int;

-- make campaign_id unique 
alter table bandit_pages
  add constraint unique_campaign_id unique (campaign_id);
  
--- create the foreign key
alter table structure
   add constraint fk_structure_bandit_pages 
   foreign key (arm_id) references bandit_pages (campaign_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, it worked but when I actually ran the program it didn't save the entries in my tables.. Could you please take a look at this ?https://stackoverflow.com/q/63597363/14041637